# sending 10-15 messages through Gcm but recieving just few of them

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am sending 10-15 messages through (Google Cloud Messaging) but when i switch on the mobile data of my phone after few hours i received just a few messages not all the messages are received by my phone .
Can u please help me with this!

Answer (score 0):

If your server sends the messages with time_to_live or collapse_key properties, it can explain why some of the messages are discarded.

time_to_live determines how long the message will be stored in GCM server prior to being sent to the device. If your device was offline was several hours, this might explain why some messages were lost.

collapse_key groups messages under a single identifier. If multiple messages with the same collapse_key reach GCM server while your device is offline, only one of them will be stored in the GCM server and delivered when the device is back online.

If none of these options apply, you should realize that the delivery of GCM messages is not guaranteed, and your app should never depend on all of them being delivered.